# Swift socket.io and node socket.io sending binary file (image)

Tags: node.js, swift, sockets

I'm trying to send a image from my nodejs server to a iOS client via socket.io

I'm using [socket.io](http://socket.io/) on server side and [socket.io-client-swift](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift) on client side.

I'm sending the binary data like this:

```
fs.readFile(imageName+".jpg", function(err, buf){
  // it's possible to embed binary data
  // within arbitrarily-complex objects
  io.emit('getPhoto', { image: true, buffer: buf });
});
```

Like its documented in http://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/#binary

But my problem is that I don't know how to handle the data on client side.

I've tried to cast it as NSInputStream but it gets a casting error on this.

On my Client side I'm doing this:

```
socket.on("getPhoto") { data,ack in
        let tmp = data[0] as? NSArray
        let buffer = tmp![1] as? NSData

        if (buffer != nil) {
            let img = UIImage(data: buffer!)
            self.setImage!(img!)
        }
}
```

How do I get the image out of this stream?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
socket.on("getPhoto") { data,ack in
    if let buffer = data[0] as? NSData {
        let img = UIImage(data: buffer)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: Cannot convert value of type'[AnyObject]' to type 'NSData' in coercion

Comment: Ah yes, data is an array. You'll need to cast to `[NSData]` or cast `data[0] as NSData`.

Comment: Oh yeah but you have to cast is with as?  But even with that it does not go into the if block.

Comment: Ah of course. The edit box is lacking fix-it support ;) Anyway, best break into the method and `po data[0]` to see what's behind the object. That should tell you the type.

Comment: The print description of data is looking like this: 
Printing description of data:
▿ 1 elements
  ▿ [0] : 2 elements
    ▿ [0] : 2 elements
      - .0 : image
    ▿ [1] : 2 elements
      - .0 : buffer

Comment: I'm using your function like in my updated posting. The problem now is, that the variable tmp is getting nil and so also the buffer.

Comment: That sounds like something's off. If `tmp` is `nil` you shouldn't even be getting a `buffer`, because `tmp!` will trap.

Answer (score 0):

Images are base64 encoded. On the server, you need:

```
function base64_encode(file) {
  var bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);
  return new Buffer(bitmap).toString('base64');
}
```

then:

```
  var base64str = base64_encode(filename);
  io.emit('getPhoto', base64str);
});
```

Once that's done on the server, the Swift 4 client side code is:

```
    socket.on("getPhoto") { data,ack in
        if let buffer = data[0] as? String {
            let decodedData = NSData(base64Encoded: buffer, options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters)
            let img = UIImage(data: decodedData! as Data)
        }
    }
```